# difference between || and ||= in this situation

Tags: ruby, logical-operators

I'm curious as to why this is happening:

```
user_uid = user[:user_uid] || next_uid
```

can return `nil`, although I would think if the first value is nil, it executes the `next_uid` method.  If i change `||` to `||=`, then it returns the results of `next_uid` if `user[:user_uid]` is `nil`

So the question is, why does

```
user_uid = user[:user_uid] ||= next_uid
```

require the `||=` operator while the following does not?

```
@terms_accepted = options[:terms_accepted] || false
```

---

relevant code:

```
    def insert(user)
      store_user(user)
    end

    def get(user_uid)
      #validations

      users[user_uid]
    end

    private

    def store_user(user)
      user_uid = user[:user_uid] || next_uid

      users[user_uid] = user

      return user_uid
    end

    def next_uid
      @memory[:user_uid] ||= 0
      "#{@memory[:user_uid] += 1}"
    end
```

---

test code in question:

```
it "stores users" do
  user = { 
    :user_uid => nil 
  }
  uid = subject.insert(user)

  assert_user_was_stored(uid)
end

def assert_user_was_stored(expected_uid)
  result = subject.get(expected_uid)

  assert_equal expected_uid, result[:user_uid]
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provided the `next_uid` code

Comment: The answer is: It doesn't. You must have messed something.

Comment: When you say "can return `nil`", what are you inspecting to see that result? I suspect you are returning/looking at `user[:user_id]`

Comment: @NeilSlater, the value is coming from tests.  I will post them

Comment: @dax please post your tests.

Comment: If you’ve solved your problem, you should either post your answer below, or, if you think your question/answer are of no relevance to future visitors, you can delete your question entirely. You should *not* simply edit your question with the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're facing this issue becuase you're not check value returned from `store_user` method, but `user[:user_uid]` value (exactly as @Neil Slater said). So, if you use `||`, `user[:user_uid]` remains `nil`. But if you use `||=`, `user[:user_uid]` is set to value returned by `next_uid` method.

Comment: how do you mean?  `uid = subject.insert_user` is setting the uid that i use to in `assert_user_was_stored` equal to the generated uid via 'next_uid' which is what `store_user` returns.

Comment: @dax you have `assert_equal expected_uid, result[:user_uid]`, `result` is returned from `get` method and thus is `user[user_uid]` value.

Comment: it's not - `get` is returning the value in the `users` hash where the key is `user_uid`.  Also, i made an edit for clarity in the test section, sorry if there's some confusion!

Comment: @dax exactly - and the `users[user_uid]` equals to `user` parameter passed into `store_user` method (look at `users[user_uid] = user` line). So, `users[user_uid][:user_uid]` equals to `user[:user_uid]`, thus it holds value other to `nil` only if you set it, for example using `||=` instead of `||` operator.

Comment: right. so now I'm back at my original question, i think.  in this line `user_uid = user[:user_uid] || next_uid` - if `user[:user_uid]` is `nil`, shouldn't the `next_uid` method be called and the `user_uid` variable be subsequently set to that without having to use `||=`? why does this `@terms_accepted = options[:terms_accepted] || false` return false if `options[:terms_accepted]` is `nil`?

Comment: @dax `next_uid` method IS called if `user[:user_uid]` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that i was assigning two values at once - `user_uid` and `user[:user_uid]` if it was unset.  A better way is to make this two lines:

```
# first set the value of user[:user_uid] if it is nil
user[:user_uid] ||= next_uid 

# then set the value of the local variable
user_uid = user[:user_uid]
```